# ¿Como puedo sumar tamaño total de los archivos adjuntos?

Tags: php, html, jquery

¿Como puedo sumar tamaño total de los archivos que adjunto en un formulario y si quito algun archivo que lo reste.?

este es el codigo jquery

```
$("#file-input").change(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
        var file = $(this).get(0).files[i];
        var e = $( "#archivo.example" ).clone().removeClass('example').removeAttr('style');
        e.find('.nombre_archivo span:first-child').text(file.name);
        e.find('.tooltiptext').text(file.name);
        e.find('.tamano_archivo').text(bytesToSize(file.size));
        e.appendTo('#archivos');
    }
});

});

function bytesToSize(bytes) {
   var sizes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
   if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
   var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
   return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
```

este es el div condo quiero sa aparezca el tamaño total de los archivos

```
<div id="total" class="cantidad_megas">0 / 4gb </div>
```

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, ¿de qué modo remueves los archivos? Es importante saberlo para determinar cómo controlar el cálculo del tamaño total. Por otra parte, si hay alguna acción final, como un botón que hay que pulsar para enviar los archivos, lo más simple sería encontrar el tamaño total desde esa acción, sin tener que preocuparse constantemente de qué archivos son añadidos o borrados. Conviene que expliques un poco el contexto para que obtengas una respuesta más óptima.

Comment: quiero crear un barra de progreso donde en funcion de los megas o gigas ocupados se llene o vacie todo esto antes de darle a enviar, que el usuario sepa que ya lleva por ejemplo 2gb de 4gb ocupados o 2mb de 4gb